# strange thing with cylinder algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, opengl, lwjgl

I want to render a cylinder in Opengl. For that i wrote an simple algorithm, that 
generates me the points mesh by the parameters radius, height, xSubDivisions and ySubDivisions:
(Java)

```
for(int yDivision = 0; yDivision < yDivisionCount; yDivision++){
    for(int xDivision = 0; xDivision < xDivisionCount; xDivision++){
        float line[] = getVboLine(xDivision, yDivision, radius, height, xDivisionCount, yDivisionCount);
        string.append(line[0] + ", " + line[1] + ", " + line[2] + ", " + line[3] + ", " + line[4] + ", ");
    }
}



public float[] getVboLine(int xDivision, int yDivision, float radius, float height, int xDivisionCount, int yDivisionCount){
    float xDegrees = 360.0f / xDivisionCount * xDivision;
    float xRadian = (float) Math.toRadians(xDegrees);
    float x = (float) Math.sin(xRadian) * radius;
    float z = (float) Math.cos(xRadian) * radius;
    float y = (float) yDivision * (height / (yDivisionCount - 1));
    float s = xDegrees * (1.0f / 360.0f);
    float t = yDivision * (1.0f / (yDivisionCount - 1));
    return new float[]{
            x, y, z, s, t
    };
}
```

The result is actually an cylinder, (i created an IBO to render this points) but sometimes, with different inputs for x and yDivisions there is a strange gap in it. 
I couldn't find a rule, but the values i found this bug with were 200, 100. 
To debug i rendered only the points. The result was:

[image]

How is this possible? One points is just missing (where i added the reed circle with paint). 
Where is the problem with my algorithm?

Comment: Is this point missing in your rendering only, or is it also not in your input?

Comment: It seems to miss in the input, too. The Problem is i can't really check this, because with small values for the divisions the doesn't  appear... But i'll try to ensure

Comment: it cannot be an mistake in the rendering actually. Im rendering with: "GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_POINTS, 0, vertices.length / 5);"
That should be all the points from the array...

Answer (score 1):

I am not JAVA coder but you are mixing int and float together

- for example:
- `xDegrees = 360.0f / xDivisionCount * xDivision`
- `[float]    [float]  [int]             [int]`
- I would rather use this:
- `xDegrees = float(360*xDivision)/float(xDivisionCount)`
- **multiplication** should go always first (if operands are >= 1)
- and **division** after that to preserve accuracy
- some weird rounding could cause your problem but it would be more noticeable for lower `xDivisionCount` not bigger one

Bug breakpoint

- add to your code last generated point
- after new point computation compute the distance from last point
- add `if  (|distance-some_avg_distance|>1e-10)`
- and add breakpoint inside
- some_avg_distance set by distance that should be there (get it from trace)
- this way you can breakpoint the point causing problems (or the next point to it)
- so you can actually see what is wrong
- my bet is that by rounding you get the same angle as prev/next point
- and therefore you do not have missing point but some duplicate instead
- you can check that also by `Blending`